# is there a way to substract days from a date in powershell?

Tags: powershell

basically I'm trying to obtain some dates by substracting days to a certain date.
I am trying

```
$today = Get-Date;
$yesterday = $today - 1;
```

that does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work, as `-1` doesn't make any sense. Is it less one second / hour / day / week / month / something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AddDays method; e.g.:

```
(get-date).AddDays(-1)
```